# Метод format с одним аргументом у класса SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android

В документации к SimpleDateFormat.format указывается, что метод принимает три параметра:

```
public StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos)
```

параметров по умолчанию у java нет. Почему нормально работает код, который вызывает format c одним параметром:

```
String getTimeString(){
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
 return df.format(c.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` имеет несколько [реализаций метода format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#method_summary):
"собственную":

```
public StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos)
```

унаследованные от `java.text.DateFormat`:

```
public final String format(Date date)
public final StringBuffer format(Object obj, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition fieldPosition)
```

унаследованная от `java.text.Format`:

```
public final String format(Object obj)
```

Comment: Точно, этот метод в DateFormat. Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Правильные ответы необходимо отмечать как принятые https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Быстрее, чем через 5 минут мне не дает отметить.